# Segfault in a matrix code using new

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I created a simple class in C++ which has a private dynamic array. In the constructor I initialize the array using new and in the destructor I free it using delete.

When I instantiate the class using Class a = Class(..); it works as expected, however it seems I cannot instantiate it using the new operator (Like Class *a = new Class(..);), I always get a segmentation fault.

What I don't understand is when I should use new to instantiate a class and when just call the constructor or should it be possible to instantiate a class either with new or by just calling the constructor.

```
float** A = new float*[3];
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    A[i] = new float[3];
}

A[0][0] = 3; A[0][1] = 3; A[0][2] = 4;
A[1][0] = 5; A[1][1] = 6; A[1][2] = 7;
A[2][0] = 1; A[2][1] = 2; A[2][2] = 3;

Matrix *M = new Matrix(A, 3, 3);

delete[] A;
delete M;
```

Below the class definition..

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    int width;
    int height;
    int stride;
    float* elements;

public:
    Matrix(float** a, int n, int m);
    ~Matrix();
};


Matrix::Matrix(float** a, int n, int m)
{
    // n: num rows
    // m: elem per rows

    elements = new float[n*m];

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++) {
            elements[i*n + j] = a[n][m];
        }
    }
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    delete[] elements;
}
```

Comment: plz show some code, there could be numerous reasons.

Comment: well elements = new float[n*m]; .. I guess thats new[]??

Comment: You also need to provide a copy constructor (and probably an assignment operator) for this to work reliably.

Comment: I suggest closing. There is no problem with operator new, just a few trivial bugs in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `i*n + j` by `i*m + j`.
and replace `a[n][m]` by `a[i][j]`

Comment: Fixed. replace `a[n][m]` by `a[i][j]` or `a[j][i]`.

Comment: Argh!! Seems like i was a bit too tired when writing this.. Thank you! But it's still strange that it does not segfault when instantiating by just calling the constructor..

Comment: Btw is there an article somewhere which explains when to use new and when to just call the constructor?

Comment: This is basically a question of the object lifetime. Once you understand the basics of C++ (or even C) variable lifetime rules, the rest should be obvious.

Comment: @Nils, it is not strange. When you instantiate the class using `Class a = Class(..);` it works as expected because your `a` is on the stack. Stack memory is valid.

Comment: May you suggest any literature?

Comment: I think it is more complicated. It works "by chance" - he is getting a buffer overflow, and depending on what is in the neighbouring memory he sees different "undefined behaviour".

Comment: Any good C/C++ primer book should do. Search and you will find.